# HyperTable Select on Column qualifier does not work in 0.9.6.5 as documented

Tags: select, hypertable

My table schema below:

```
hypertable> show create table users;                         

CREATE TABLE GROUP_COMMIT_INTERVAL "100" users (             
    'column_name_beta' MAX_VERSIONS 1,                                                                         
     ACCESS GROUP audience ('column_name_beta'),                                   
)                                                            

Data looks like this, when I do, 'SELECT * from users'

1000            column_name_beta:80069355        
1000000038      column_name_beta:26090761
100000008       column_name_beta:16589206
1000000112      column_name_beta:5536782
```

So, my question is, When I do:
    SELECT column_name_beta:80069355 FROM users;

It returns no rows. Why? I have tried single quote, double quotes et all. Please help. As per
documentation here, http://hypertable.com/documentation/reference_manual/hql#select::Column Qualifier Predicate, it should work? What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the read from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/hypertable-user/ilBlGIIwh68/a2TWziSpkJcJ, I tried,

```
SELECT column_name_beta:'80069355' FROM users;
```

and it worked.